# Ignoring regex at end of string

Tags: ruby, regex

I have an invalid JSON response like this:

```
{"a": 1, "b": {...}}{"x": 2, "y": 3}
```

I'm unable to fix the source, so I have to fix it on my end.

I want to extract out only this JSON chunk: `{"a": 1, "b": {...}}`

It's because it's appending a second chunk of metadata JSON `{"x": 2, "y": 3}` that I want to ignore.

How do I format my regex to either

a) only take the first JSON blob (up until the space right before the last `{`)

b) strip out the last JSON chunk (I would say look for the last `{` in the string so I can split right before it.

Method B is probably easiest

Comment: I don't know if I understood well what you want, but you can use this regex to catch the part you want.
"(\{.*\})\{"
I don't know with ruby but with most regex methods you can get the result you caught and put it into a string.

Comment: @pLOPeGG thanks ill give that a shot

Comment: apologies @Tallboy, I had no idea that this response was coming form an external API. Perhaps, you should try to get it fixed by reporting it to them. In the meanwhile, How are you diffrentiating the valid JSON from invalid JSON in your example `{"a": 1, "b": {...}}{"x": 2, "y": 3}`.

Comment: Also to the person who voted to close this...........why? It is a direct regex question.

Comment: I almost solved it by doing this `/(.+)({.+)$/`, but it doesn't work with multiline strings, and for some reason if I replace `$` with `\z` it stops working.. still trying to figure that one out. As for the valid JSON comment, that's a good point but I really am not trying to validate it as I know its valid. Im just trying to extract out the last chunk, starting with the last `{...}` block of the multi-line string (some of the JSON values include `\r\n`)

Comment: lol @Tallboy your bragging made me laugh (no offense :p). I still think, you should contact the developers of the external API and get it sorted out. You will be doing them a favor by reporting it. Also, I did not know that you could not change the source because you never mentioned it anywhere.

Comment: Are you assuming a regular expression must be used to obtain the desired result or are you only interested in methods that employ a regular expression? If the former, you have descirbed a so-called [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/), as the use of a regex is just one approach here.

Comment: As written, the braces in `}{` are not separated by a space (or any other character). May there be spaces? If so, how many?

Comment: As an aside, if you give names to your example's input objects (e.g., `str = '{"a": 1, "b": {...}}{"x": 2, "y": 3}'`) readers can refer to those variables (`str`) in comments and answers without having to define them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can think right now, you'll never have an open bracket next to a close bracket in JSON, so you might be able to get away with just a simple split:

```
source = '{"a": 1, "b": {"c": 2}}{"x": 2, "y": 3}'
json = source.split(/(?<=\})\s*\{/)[0]
JSON.parse(json)
# => {"a"=>1, "b"=>{"c"=>2}}
```

Comment: oh crap!! youre right. I tried thinking of a split situation and totally didn't even think o fthat. I can just check for `}{`

Comment: It's super dirty, not something I would use in production in case one of the other values contains `}{` but for this purpose I think this will be fine

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regular expression, but it's more direct to just pull out the string you want.

```
str = '{"a": 1, "b": {"c": 2}}{"x": 2, "y": 3}'

s = str[0, str.index('}{')]
  #=> "{\"a\": 1, \"b\": {\"c\": 2}"

puts s
  #=> {"a": 1, "b": {"c": 2}
```

Here I've assumed that, as in the example, there are no spaces between the braces in `'}{'`. If there may be zero or more spaces, as here:

```
str = '{"a": 1, "b": {"c": 2}}   {"x": 2, "y": 3}'
```

use the following (which, alas, uses a regex, albeit a simple one):

```
puts str[0, str.index(/\} *\{/)]
  #=> {"a": 1, "b": {"c": 2}
```